# MongoDB/Mongoose: using different schemes for different types of document in the same collection

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema

Say I have documents in a collection "posts". I want to treat these documents as one collection - for example, to search through them or run db.posts.find() on all of them together.

However, there are distinctly different types of post, which should ideally have different schemas. For example, a "text" post could be:

```
post_type: "text",
author: String,
title: String,
body: String
```

And an "image" post could be:

```
post_type: "image",
uri: String,
thumbnail: String
```

Is there a clean way to define multiple schemas for different types of document in the same collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for both of them into one,

your model :

```
post_type: "text",
author: String,
title: String,
body: String,
uri: String,
thumbnail: String
```

When saving just use the fields which are needed.

1. saving as **type : text**

```
const body = {
 post_type: "text",
 author: String,
 title: String,
 body: String
}

your_model.save(body);
```

2. saving as **type : image**

```
const body = {
 post_type: "image",
 uri: String,
 thumbnail: String
}

your_model.save(body);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this approach feels like it makes for a very messy schema. The example I gave was simplified - in reality I'll have several "types" of document, with dozens of unique fields each. I was interested if there's a good way to handle this.

Comment: Better to use in different schema

Comment: How would I then achieve what I want, i.e. find() on all of these different schemas at once? I suppose I could set up my own helper function that runs Promise.all() with find() on multiple schemas, but then I wouldn't be able to use MongoDB features like limit()

Comment: then you must try the one i told you, It'll only make your Model file messy, but you can achieve your other functionality easier.

Comment: @dan674  You can also try this approach [Mongoose : SubDocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)